# При входе в Apple SignIn ошибка Username or Password incorrect

Tags: ios, ionic

Я пытаюсь протестировать приложение на симуляторе Ios.
Для тестирования нужно залогиниться в через Apple Sign In.

1. То есть захожу в Настройки - Apple Sign in
2. Ввожу пароль и емаил
3. Ввожу код, который пришел на телефон
4. А затем выходить ошибка [Icloud] Username or Password incorrect

Вот скринщот:
http://joxi.ru/MAjROqLujyvdVA

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что нужно сделать, чтобы залогиниться в симуляторе Ios?**

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас постоянно возникает такая ошибка, а логин и пароль верны, то нужно

- Зайти на https://www.icloud.com/
- Ввести свои учетные данные
- Принять пользовательское соглашение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь вход в симуляторе должен заработать